# Verify Passwords Match in Windows Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm creating a script to handle unattended domain joining for the school district I work at.  We have several IT guys who handle sysprep, so I'm creating a script that will encrypt passwords to use for Add-Computer.

What I am having trouble with is having a script that takes two password entries, and restarts if they don't match, but continues if they do.  What I've tried so far:

```
$s = {write-host "running script}
&$s
$pwd1 = Read-Host -AsSecureString "Enter Password"
$pwd2 = Read-Host -AsSecureString "Enter Again"
If($pwd1 -ceq $pwd2) {
Write-host "match"
} else {
&$s
}
```

I would like to have the script automatically make the user retry until both passwords match.

EDIT: Figured it out!  Here's the code for reference. Thanks to RowdyVinson!

```
do {
Write-Host "I am here to compare the password you are entering..."
$pwd1 = Read-Host "Password" -AsSecureString
$pwd2 = Read-Host "Re-enter Password" -AsSecureString
$pwd1_text = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pwd1))
$pwd2_text = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pwd2))
}
while ($pwd1_text -ne $pwd2_text)
Write-Host "Passwords matched"
```

Comment: In general encryption passwords is the wrong solution, when the attacker gains admin access he will get the database including the encrypted passwords and the encryption key.

Comment: I considered that, but we are a relatively small district, and my co-workers were just getting tired of putting in credentials each time for domain join, so I have my script run on first login, then (via unattend.xml) another batch file in C:\Windows\Panther deletes everything, once the domain has been joined.  Also, the encrypted passwords are created as the master image is, which never gains internet access until the domain join.  As soon as the domain is joined, the files go bye-bye.  Someone would have to come steal the HDD.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're looking to compare two secure strings, so you'll need to decrypt them first. Here's an implementation of what you're trying to do:

```
Write-Host "Hey..!! I am here to compare the password you are entering..."
$pwd1 = Read-Host "Passowrd" -AsSecureString
$pwd2 = Read-Host "Re-enter Passowrd" -AsSecureString
$pwd1_text = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pwd1))
$pwd2_text = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pwd2))


if ($pwd1_text -ceq $pwd2_text) {
Write-Host "Passwords matched"
} else {
Write-Host "Passwords differ"
}
```

and this is where I got that from: http://techibee.com/powershell/compare-secure-strings-entered-through-powershell/422

also possibly relevant: https://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/2010/03/23/show-password-in-plaintext-by-using-get-credential-in-powershell/

Comment: I could never bring myself to like that method of getting back to a plain text string. Just for the sake of having an alternative: `(New-Object PSCredential '.', $SecureString).GetNetworkCredential().Password`. Alas it's still moderately convoluted.

Comment: Thanks that worked!  My next question would be, how do I get it to restart if the passwords differ?  So the script makes you keep retrying until they match.