# If Statement in Powershell always responds with the same output

Tags: powershell, if-statement

So i want a script that sets the Administrator password.
I want the user to input it twice and then check if it matches.
Ive already tried to switch the conditions -eq and -ne in the two if statements, but it didnt change anything

```
$Password = Read-Host -AsSecureString 'Passwort des lokalen Administrators setzen' #input admin password
$PasswordRepeat = Read-Host -AsSecureString 'Passwort wiederholen' #repeat password
if ($Password -eq $PasswordRepeat) {
    $UserAccount = Get-LocalUser -Name "Admin"
    $UserAccount | Set-LocalUser -Password $Password
    'Passwort wurde gesetzt' #password was set
    ''
    Read-Host 'Enter druecken um das Script zu schliessen' #press enter to close
}
elseif ($Password -ne $PasswordRepeat) {
    'Passwoerter stimmen nicht ueberein' #passwords do not match
    ''
    Read-Host 'Enter druecken um das Script zu schliessen' #press enter to close
}
```

So when the password and passwordrepeat match it should change the password and output that the password is set. But if i input the same password twice it also prints out that the passwords do not match, and when i input two different passwords it also says that they dont match

Comment: Comparation between secure string doesn’t work it’s just what you have to change get 2 text value off passwords and compare thoses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find at this url : [Verify Passwords Match in Windows Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38901752/verify-passwords-match-in-windows-powershell)

I think this can respond :

```
Write-Host "Hey..!! I am here to compare the password you are entering..."
$pwd1 = Read-Host "Passowrd" -AsSecureString
$pwd2 = Read-Host "Re-enter Passowrd" -AsSecureString
$pwd1_text = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pwd1))
$pwd2_text = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pwd2))


if ($pwd1_text -ceq $pwd2_text) {
Write-Host "Passwords matched"
} else {
Write-Host "Passwords differ"
}
```