# How to assign value to a variable in Batch file by running powershell script for it?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, variables, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have two files one is batch file named **validator.bat** and another one is powershell script **checker.ps1**

***validator.bat***

```
    @echo OFF
    set/p "pass=>"
    echo %pass%
```

The variable pass is to be assigned the value using powerhell script.

***checker.ps1***

```
    $pwd1 = Read-Host "Enter your passowrd: "
    $pwd2 = 'password'
    if ($pwd1 -ceq $pwd2) {
    Write-Host "matched"
    } else {
    Write-Host "differ"
    }
```

I want to assign the output string *"matched"/"differ"* to the pass variable in bat file but using only powershell script or its code.
I searched a lot on Google and Youtube but I could not Find the solution to my problem.
Please help me.

Comment: environmental variables are _per session_. so, if you make/change an EnvVar in cmd.exe using `set` ...it will only be seen by that session and sessions that are children of that session. can you do this all in one session?

Comment: Yes I can do it in one session.
I would need to run full code of powershell by writing it in bat file but that won't allow me to input data.
How will I get the value then?

Comment: if you do everything in powershell ... then you won't need to play with the problems of mixing BAT/CMD with PoSh. if you cannot do that, then the `save to a file` idea may be your only hope.

Comment: I wanted to do everything in powershell but I know the codes for bat file for some tasks which I don't know how to convert for powershell. And there is some functionality I know in powershell which I don't know how to use in Bat.

Comment: thank you for the "why" of it! [*grin*] you will likely be better off if you work on translating things to ONE powershell script ... but if you are in an urgent hurry, then do something like what is shown in the Answer by DougMaurer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

validator.bat

```
@echo OFF
for /f %%a in ('powershell -file checker.ps1') do set "pass=%%~a"
echo %pass%
```

checker.ps1

```
$pwd1 = Read-Host "Enter your password: "
$pwd2 = 'password'
if ($pwd1 -ceq $pwd2) {
    Write-Host "matched"
} else {
    Write-Host "differ"
}
```

Note, this will not mask the password as it's typed. You'd need to use `-AsSecureString` on read-host and then convert it to a regular string to compare it. There may be a way to compare secure strings that I am not aware of.

Comment: You can use [ConvertFrom-SecureString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/convertfrom-securestring?view=powershell-7) to convert a secure-string into a 460-character normal string. That could be stored in the script (in place of `'password'`) and converted to a secure-string with ConvertTo-SecureString. However, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38901898/2096401) you have to go through a slightly tortuous route to compare them.

Comment: Yeah, I had already done that part of getting secure password, hashing it and comparing it.

Comment: Thank you so much for solving my problem 

Comment: Here is the answer on how to compare secure strings.
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38901752/verify-passwords-match-in-windows-powershell