# Graphic CLI changed after run the powershell command in batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

After the PowerShell code the batch file CLI is a little different, **i want to change it back**

You can see the font changed and the color changed a little

Before PowerShell command

[image]

After PowerShell command

[image]

```
@echo off
echo +==================================================+
echo ^|**********************Login***********************^|
echo +==================================================+
echo.
echo Login
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set /p input=Username:
::powershell command
set "psCommand=powershell -Command "$pword = read-host 'Enter password' -AsSecureString ; ^
    $BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pword); ^
      [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)""
        for /f "usebackq delims=" %%p in (`%psCommand%`) do set passwords=%%p
)
if %passwords% == 123 goto sucess
exit
END LOCAL
:sucess
cls
echo welcom back %Username%!
echo :)
pause
exit
```

I see the different

before Powershell command

[image]

after the Powershell command

[image]

Comment: `Color 17` should suffice to reset the color.

Curious though, what is the point of using powershell secure string method if you read it into a variable that can be read by the user. Would it not make more sense to store the comparison value as a secure string and comparing them with a method such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38901898/12343998)?

I'm not seeing any reason here why you wouldn't just use powershell.

Comment: when copy your powershell command, jion in to one line, remove  multiline carrets it work without console property changing. Try to reformat line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presume the problem stems from `chcp 65001` being in effect, i.e. the UTF-8 code page.

With code page `65001` in effect, `powershell.exe` - the [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) of *Windows PowerShell* - indeed unfortunately exhibits the symptom you describe: the currently selected font is changed to a  legacy *raster font* with limited glyph (character) support.

The following command demonstrates the problem (run from `cmd.exe`):

```
:: Unexpectedly switches to a raster font.
:: Note: No longer occurs in PowerShell (Core) 7+, with pwsh.exe
chcp 65001 & powershell -noprofile -c "'hi'"
```

---

You have the following **options**:

- Run your batch file in [*Windows Terminal*](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal), available [in the Microsoft Store](https://aka.ms/windowsterminal) instead of in a legacy console window.
- You can *temporarily* switch to a code page *other* than `65001`, *assuming it still supports all the characters you need*; applied to the example above:

  ```
  chcp 437 & powershell -noprofile -c "'hi'" & chcp 65001
  ```
- You can switch from Windows PowerShell to [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), the install-on-demand, cross-platform successor edition. Its [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), `pwsh.exe`, no longer exhibits the problem.

Comment: will the `chcp 437` has the same problem as `chcp 65001` , and is there other code pages that not change the font?

Comment: hm i see `chcp 437 & powershell -noprofile -c "'█'"` but the █ is show in cmd console but in file batch file is not it will become Γûê
how can i print out █ ?

Comment: How did you know that i use `chcp 65001` ?

Comment: @khuongnguyen, I inferred that you're using code page `65001` from the PowerShell behavior you describe. `437` should work fine for a workaround, but you're then invariably limited _to the 256 characters this page supports_ - see [Code Page 437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code%20page%20437)